# High level description of a priority queue with adjustable priority

Tags: java, graph-theory, priority-queue

While implementing Dijkstra's and Prim's algorithms, we require a priority queue with adjustable priorities. I Understand how an array based implementation of the heap functions, but I don't understand how to make the priorities adjustable. I've read that a hashmap allows this, but I don't understand how.

Can someone please give me a high level description of this implementation using a hashmap using an example. a,b,c,d,e,f have priorities 2,4,0,6,1,9 respectively, how would I keep a track of their indices after insertion into the heap? if b's priority is changed to 8 how would this work?.

Please refer me to any additional material I may require to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Heap<Key extends Comparable<Key>> {
    private Key[] heap;
    private int maxN, n;
    private HashMap<Key, Integer> map;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Heap(int maxN) {
        if(maxN < 0 ) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.maxN = maxN;
        n = 0;
        heap = (Key[]) new Comparable[maxN];
        map = new HashMap<>(maxN);
    }

    boolean isEmpty() {
        return n == 0;
    }

    boolean insert(Key e) {
        if(n +1 > maxN) throw new IllegalArgumentException("maximum capacity reached " + maxN);
        heap[n] = e;
        map.put(e,n);
        int i = n++;
        swim(i);
        return true;
    }

    Key extractMin() {
        if(n == 0) throw new NoSuchElementException("Priority queue underflow ");
        Key min = heap[0];
        swap(0, n-1);
        map.remove(min);
        n--;
        sink(0);
        return min;
    }

    void delete(Key e){
        if(!map.containsKey(e)) return; //throw new NoSuchElementException(e+" does not exist ");
        int j = map.get(e);
        swap(j, n-1);
        map.remove(e);
        n--;
        if(!swim(j))
            sink(j);
    }

    void decreasePriority(Key e){
        if(map.containsKey(e)){
            int j = map.get(e);
            swim(j);
        }
        else insert(e);
    }

    private void swap(int i, int j) {
        Key t = heap[i];
        heap[i] = heap[j];
        heap[j] = t;
        map.replace(heap[i], i);
        map.replace(heap[j], j);
    }
    private boolean swim(int j){
        boolean change = false;
        int parent;
        while( (parent = (j-1)/2 ) >= 0){
            if(heap[j].compareTo(heap[parent]) < 0){
                swap(j,parent);
                j = parent;
                change = true;
            }
            else break;
        }
        return change;
    }
    private void sink(int j){
        while(j <= n/2 - 1){
            int leftChild = j*2 + 1, rightChild = leftChild + 1, s;
            if(rightChild >= n)
                s = leftChild;
            else
                s = heap[leftChild].compareTo(heap[rightChild]) < 0 ? leftChild : rightChild;
            if(heap[j].compareTo(heap[s]) > 0){
                swap(j,s);
                j = s;
            }
            else break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String res = "[";
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
            res += heap[i] + ", ";
        }
        res += heap[i]+"]";
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The changes in the MinPQ will be made using `swim()` and `sink()` operations to adjust the priority

for example `decreaseKey()` will decrease the priority related to the vertex it's

just calling `swim()` operation

, And `increasekey()` will increase the priority related to the vertex it's

just calling `sink()` operation

The implementation should looks like:

```
    private void swim(int k) {
        while (k > 1 && greater(k/2, k)) {
            swap(k, k/2);
            k = k/2;
        }
    }

    private void swap(int k) {
        while (2*k <= n) {
            int j = 2*k;
            if (j < n && greater(j, j+1)) j++;
            if (!greater(k, j)) break;
            exch(k, j);
            k = j;
        }
    }
```

More resources Princeton:

1. [Shortest path lecture](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/)
2. [IndexMinPQ code](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/IndexMinPQ.java.html)
3. [DijkstraSP code](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/DijkstraSP.java.html)

Comment: where can I look up swim() and sink()?

Comment: In link of IndexMinPQ : https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/IndexMinPQ.java.html

Comment: I have added to the post

Comment: Thanks a ton, been stuck with this for quite some time now.

Comment: you are welcome :), could you approve the answer :D

Comment: can I contact you for a query?

Comment: sure yes you can

Comment: hi, sorry to bother you again, but I've been stuck with this problem for days now ,don't know what else to do, can I email you or (any other mode of communication )with a small query, shouldn't take more than a few minutes for you, but if you feel it would,no problems in that case, but could you please just take a look at it.

Comment: Sure you can contact me for any query